# How to set day of a date in moment?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, momentjs

I want to set the date to another day, then add 1 to the date.

```
    onModalPrevDate=()=>{
        this.closeModal();
        let d=this.state.selectedDay;
        let dateContext = Object.assign({}, this.props.dateContext);
        let c=moment(dateContext).set("days",d);  //not working as intended
        let f=moment(c).add(1,"day");
        let a=f.format("D");
        this.onDayClick(a);
    }
```

moment(dateContext).set("days",d); is not working as intended. have tried "day" instead of "days" still not working.

Comment: The documentation will help -> http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/set/

Comment: yes using let c=moment(dateContext).set("date",d); worked

Answer (score 27, accepted):

use "date" instead of "days"

```
let c=moment(dateContext).set("date",d);
```

Comment: For those who are wondering, [`day`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/day/) sets the day of the week (0-6)